# How do I implement a list with columns in a easy way using html, css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a site, where one needs to choose an element from a detailed list (one with columns that show its type, etc.) and pass it to another list. I've asked this question before and someone gave me slickGrid as a solution. However that is not quite what I want, because slickGrid gives me a spreadsheet, and I want a list with the details in columns, and be able to easily pass around information from one list to another.

Thanx in advance.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you can use 3rd party libraries, it sounds like you want to have a look at [jQuery UI's Draggable & Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable).

There's a similar question here that deals with dragging between two lists: [jQuery Draggable + Sortable - How to drag and drop between two scrollable lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109757/jquery-draggable-sortable-how-to-drag-and-drop-between-two-scrollable-lists)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. I want two lists side by side with columns in them (as in a file browser in detailed view) and I want to be able to click on a item on the left list, click an icon, and see it go to the right list. The columns are very important, because I want to be able to show detailed information about each item.

Comment: @dasen666: Ah, so you want multiple columns per list? Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

How about the jqgrid!
Please see here detailed document for it, http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm
seeing your requirement , you can initialize two grids, and put a button on first grid's toolbar, using which you can perform desired operation on selected row.